# Mysql; Data Total

Tags: mysql

```
 ID  fileName    userName
 1   abc1        Emre
 2   abc2        Abc
 3   abc2        John
 4   abc1        Rick
 5   abc1        Rick
```

> *Screen print:*
>
> ---
>
> **The top downloaded files :** *1)* abc1 *2)* abc2

I want to show the most downloaded files. How can I do a mysql query?

*(Sorry for Eng)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get an aggregate `COUNT()` grouped by `fileName`. Sort in descending order by download count, and limit by the number of results you want returned (if necessary).

```
SELECT 
  fileName, 
  COUNT(*) AS downloads
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY fileName
ORDER BY downloads DESC
/* Optionally limit the number returned */
LIMIT 2;
```

Comment: A `FROM` clause might be helpful. :-)

Comment: @Editor: You can say "thanks" by accepting an answer. Just click on the outlined checkmark next to the answer you found most helpful.

Comment: Can I show the total number of file downloads? Is it possible? `abc1 (3), abc2 (2)`

Comment: @Editor that's exactly what this query shows. `COUNT(*) as downloads` gives you that information.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT fileName, COUNT(*) AS DownloadCount
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY fileName
    ORDER BY DownloadCount DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `COUNT` aggregate function by grouping on the `fileName`

```
select fileName, count(1) as qty_dl 
  from your_table 
 group by fileName 
 order by qty_dl desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `fileName`, COUNT(`fileName`) AS `count`
FROM `tableName`
GROUP BY `fileName`
ORDER BY `count` DESC
LIMIT 2;
```